# Html2Canvas Rotated td is showing only first 3 letters

Tags: html2canvas

I tried using htmltocanvas to make png of selected html in my web page, though its giving perfect output but i am facing few issues which are as follows:

1. Rotated td's in which text is coming through knockout is showing only first 3 letters in the converted image via html2canvas.
2. dotted borders are coming as solid borders.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found out that child div was taking the overflow hidden of parent.
Hence issue 1 solves still issue in dotted border though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed dashed borders.
Solved by drawing the borders myself, over the canvas returned by html2canvas.

Here are the steps:

1. Collect all border data in the HTML;
2. Remove the borders from the HTML, so the `html2canvas` wont draw them;
3. Call the `html2canvas`;
4. In the `onrendered` callback, draw the borders and restore the borders in the HTML.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snu9xs73/). The `tocanvas` function has the same signature of `html2canvas`.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es6Gf.png)